# Onclick button beginer's android app isn't running:

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I am new here,posting my first question.So this android project about showing a layout onclick of button,isn't running.When I run it,the emulator opens but my project isn't visible on it. I am trying to show another layout when button is clicked.Can anyone help me out? 
My layouts are :activity_main,tutorial1 (layout to be showed after button:tutorial1 is clicked),splash(which is showed for 5 seconds on opening).
Also manja is name of sound that is played on opening,for 5 seconds.
Here's my code:
MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.thebasics;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 MediaPlayer logoMusic;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle AmanIsAwesome) {
        super.onCreate(AmanIsAwesome);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        logoMusic = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.manja);
        logoMusic.start();

        Thread logoTimer= new Thread (){
         public void run (){
             try{
                 sleep(5000);
                 Intent menuIntent=new Intent("com.example.thebasics.MENU");
                 startActivity(menuIntent);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             finally{
                   finish();
             }
         }
        };
        logoTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        logoMusic.release();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Menu.java:

```
package com.example.thebasics;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class menu extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button tut1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1);
        tut1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent ("com.example.thebasics.TUTORIAL"));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

Tutorial.java:

```
       package com.example.thebasics;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Tutorial extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tutorial1);
    }

}
    }
```

The basics androidmanifest:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.thebasics"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/download"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.thebasics.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.thebasics.MENU"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.thebasics.MENU" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.thebasics.TUTORIAL"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.thebasics.TUTORIAL" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
     </activity>       

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Also the console is showing the error:- Emulator[ Warning: No DNS servers found]
whats this?

Comment: In menu.java and tutorial.java you have mentioned same code...layout is same...also post the tutorial.java code

Comment: I have posted and made the changes in intent and removed the action android:name field,posted the tutorial.java code and my project is showing on the emulator but after splash screen it shows "stops unexpectedly" error.Also,the project you gave,has some error in res in the crunch folder,I don't how to fix that because I am totally new to android! :)

Comment: Just Clean this Project and run it again..Its complete :)

Comment: Firstly,you're awesome! But can you tell me what mistakes I did and anything new you added to make that work?

Comment: Thanks.First you have used Intent wrong...second you mentioned activities wrongly in the manifest.xml.Third you are using the same layout in multiple activities.Cheers :)

Comment: Hi,just a one more error in my project,I edited it as you said removed the extra lines from manifest like I saw in your sample,but I am getting error in manifest which is "activity should end with > or />" but I have ended activities properly,still it is showing this error,also I have cleaned it still the error prevails! :/

Comment: Just write like this <activity android:name="com.example.thebasics.Menu1"></activity>..com.example.thebasics is the package name and Menu1 is the activity inside package..Also please accept my post as answer :)

Comment: I am writting like this :<activity android:name="com.example.thebasics.Menu"></activity>
<activity android:name="com.example.thebasics.Tutorial"></activity>.Still the error is there..!

Comment: Press Ctrl+Z to undo and just clean your project and do as i do in my project...By seeing these two lines of code i cant figure out your problem..If any more help you want contact me on my email :)

Comment: OKay I will do that and tell you latter! :D thanks

Comment: I got it! I wasn't naming the intent properly and I came to know that it's case sensitive so I corrected Menu to menu in my project and it worked!!Feeling so happy oh! and btw happy new year!! Thanks a ton!

Comment: hmmm nice ...Happy New Year :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have uploaded a fully working of your project.Download it from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k0ynkqvcq2t5voh/sample.zip).Also use Intent as other people mentioned.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this or getApplicationContext(), Tutorial.class);
  /* First argument is your current activity.You can also mention it i.e CurrentActivity.this */
  /* Second argument is the class where you wanna go i.e OtherActivity.class */
  startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead :

```
startActivity(new Intent (context, Tutorial.class));
```

Your way of doing it is strange too :

dont do this :

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.thebasics.TUTORIAL"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.thebasics.TUTORIAL" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Just do :

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.thebasics.Tutorial"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

 </activity>
```

Same thing for the other one.

This doesn't exist :

```
<action android:name="com.example.thebasics.TUTORIAL" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This line code

```
new Intent ("com.example.thebasics.TUTORIAL")
```

Creates [intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28java.lang.String%29) with action name "com.example.thebasics.TUTORIAL"

What you want is:

```
startActivity(new Intent (MainActivity.this, Tutorial.class));
```

Just like Tsunaze suggested.

Answer (score 0):

do as follow

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Tutorial.class);
// set some flags here according to your need
startActivity(intent);

Intent intent = new Intent(context, Menu.class);
// set some flags here according to your need
startActivity(intent);
```

and remove this from your manifest file as this is wrong

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.thebasics.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 </intent-filter>


<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.thebasics.TUTORIAL" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Hello,thanks for your help and I've made the changes as you suggested,now my project is visible on emulator but after showing splash screen for 5 sec it shows "Thebasics stopped unexpectedly"error.Please help...!!

Comment: Oh! Thanks! but please can you tell me why we remove those lines of intent-filter from manifest?and when we use those? and we don't?

Comment: read these documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html and if answer has helped you please accept and vote up :)